# Update form fields based on checkbox selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form with 6 check-boxes and 6 hidden text fields which need to be changed based on checkbox selections

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Auto" id="auto_Auto" name="auto" class="checkbox form_elem_auto"><label for="auto_Auto" id="label_auto">Auto</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" value="Home" id="home_Home" name="home" class="checkbox form_elem_home"><label for="home_Home" id="label_home">Home</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" value="Life" id="life_Life" name="life" class="checkbox form_elem_life"><label for="life_Life" id="label_life">Life</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" value="Health" id="health_Health" name="health" class="checkbox form_elem_health"><label for="health_Health" id="label_health">Health</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" value="Medicare" id="medicare_Medicare" name="medicare" class="checkbox form_elem_medicare"><label for="medicare_Medicare" id="label_medicare">Medicare</label>
<br />

<input type="checkbox" value="Renters" id="renters_Renters" name="renters" class="checkbox form_elem_renters"><label for="renters_Renters" id="label_renters">Renters</label>
<br />


<input id="auto_h" name="auto_h" class="hidden" value="FALSE" ><br />
<input id="home_h" name="home_h" class="hidden" value="FALSE" ><br />
<input id="life_h" name="life_h" class="hidden" value="FALSE" ><br />
<input id="health_h" name="health_h" class="hidden" value="FALSE" ><br />
<input id="medicare_h" name="medicare_h" class="hidden" value="FALSE" ><br />
<input id="renters_h" name="renters_h" class="hidden" value="FALSE" >
```

I would like to when checkbox `id="auto_Auto" name="auto"` is checked, the hidden field be updated with **TRUE** and when left unchecked to be updated/remain at **FALSE**. 
Similarly with other check-boxes and their hidden form equivalents

I have tried modifying the jQuery triggers from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28982645/1302672) but whenever check-boxes are checked, all the hidden fields get updated with **TRUE**

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtq4cbzw/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target specific input with this code:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name') + '_h';
    $('#' + name).val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
}).change();
$("input[type=text]").on('keyup', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('name').replace(/_h$/, '');
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $('[name="' + name + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('[name="' + name + '"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtq4cbzw/3/)

Comment: Thanks, this almost works, but when checkbox is not checked at all, the value does not remain FALSE. Only if you check and uncheck the value is set to FALSE.

Comment: @valdroni just call `.change();` to trigger change event.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
       var name = $(this).attr('name');
       $("#"+name+"_h").val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'); 

    });
    var name = $(this).attr('name').replace(/_h$/, '');
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $('[name="' + name + '"]').prop('checked', true);
   } else {
      $('[name="' + name + '"]').prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

You always have reference using name. Your hidden input has `id: CLICKED_OBJECT.name+"_h"`
**UPDATE:**

Set value to "false" by default

```
<input type="text" id="auto_h" name="auto_h" class="hidden" value='FALSE'><br />
<input type="text" id="home_h" name="home_h" class="hidden"  value='FALSE'><br />
<input type="text" id="life_h" name="life_h" class="hidden"  value='FALSE'><br />
<input type="text" id="health_h" name="health_h" class="hidden"  value='FALSE'><br />
<input type="text" id="medicare_h" name="medicare_h" class="hidden"  value='FALSE'><br />
<input type="text" id="renters_h" name="renters_h" class="hidden"  value='FALSE'>
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works, and same as jcubic's example, but when checkbox is not checked at all, the value does not remain FALSE. Only if you check and uncheck the value is set to FALSE.

Comment: set it `false` by default

Comment: Thank you it works but hardcoding the FALSE values in form

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `$.nextAll` is setting values for all the fields.

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {

        //$(this).nextAll('.hidden').val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
        $('#'+$(this).attr('name')+'_h').val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
    });
    $("input[type=text]").on('keyup', function () {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            $(this).prevAll('.auto_h:first').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).prevAll('.auto_h:first').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this also works, although the prevAlll is targetting a single hidden field

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for the hidden field based on it's attribute

```
$("[name="+$(this).attr('name')+"_h]").val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qua0epjd/)

Comment: Thank you this was helpful.